# Angular ng-model Over Several Views

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, data-binding

Can I use ng-model to build up an object over several views?

For instance, say in view1 I have

```
<input ng-model='myObject.firstName'>
```

And in view2 I have

```
<input ng-model='myObject.lastName'>
```

And in view3 I have

```
<input ng-model='myObject.email'>
```

The idea being you could hit a submit button in the last view, and return the object somewhere.

My initial approach to this is to have a service which declares an empty object, then have functions in the service which allow the controllers using the service to add their view input to that object, then return the object.

However I feel like this is quite a roundabout way of doing it!

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: If myObject is part of a controller and you will update this object only in this controll then... why not? That will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a service for that. Here an example with 3 controllers sharing the same object using 3 directives `ng-model`. Each controller modify the `tested.value` property, but you can use differents properties of course.

```js
angular.module('test', []).factory('tested', function() {
  return {
     value : '123'  
  };
}).controller('ctrl1', function($scope, tested) {
  $scope.tested = tested;  
}).controller('ctrl2', function($scope, tested) {
  $scope.tested = tested;  
}).controller('ctrl3', function($scope, tested) {
  $scope.tested = tested;  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="tested.value" />
    {{ tested.value }}
  </div>
  
  <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
    <input type="text" ng-model="tested.value" />
    {{ tested.value }}
  </div>
  
  <div ng-controller="ctrl3">
    <input type="text" ng-model="tested.value" />
    {{ tested.value }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! About to head to work so will let you know later if it's what I'm looking for!

Comment: Excellent, short, functional. And with code snippet this is great! +1

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for! +1

Answer (score 0):

Since each view has its controller, the only way to share data is with a service of type "provider", "service" or "factory".

You could then modify your object from each controller with the methods you talk about.

In the end, to notify each view something changed, the service methods could raise an event from the service :

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('somethingChanged', myObject);
```

And each controller could listen with:

```
$scope.$on('somethingChanged', function(data) { 
});
```